# How to implement FIFO with php coding?

Tags: php, arrays, stock

I would like to Implement FIFO with PHP coding.

How can I write php coding minus stock by using FIFO?

In Examle,

```
Sotck In

ID Itemname QtyIn Price Total Date
1  A         2   $3    5$   01-jan-2013
2  A         4   $2    8$   02-jan-2013 
3  B         3   $2    6$   01-jan-2013


Sotck Out

ID Itemname QtyOut  Date
1  A         3   05-jan-2013

Than i will insert into transactions as the following:

ID Itemname QtyOut Price Total Date
1  A         2   $3    6$   05-jan-2013
2  A         1   $2    2$   05-jan-2013 



Sotck In Remain Balance :

ID Itemname Qty Price Total Date
1  A         0   $3    0$   01-jan-2013
2  A         3   $2    6$   02-jan-2013 
3  B         3   $2    6$   01-jan-2013
```

Please give solution and tell flow in php check and minus qtyIn by date asc.

Regards,

Comment: You could write a trigger that runs when transactions is inserted into and performs the operations on stock in (or fails if it would leave stock in in an invalid state, like negative quantity), or you could write PHP code that selects from stock in, verifies that the operation would be successful and updates the rows that need to be updated if so.

Answer (score 0):

FIFO has nothing to do with your problem.
Just use a MySQL database and learn about the ORDER BY keyword. Your goal seems to be some sort of persistent data storage anyhow.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sorting-rows.html If after reading that link you still don't understand it, then you're beyond help.